# Firebird SQL Script command string limitation

Tags: delphi, firebird

Does anybody know, if there is a command string size limitation in Firebird?

When executing a small "insert" script it works perfectly, but when the script has a lot of lines it returns the following errer: `"Unexpected end of command - line X, column Y"`.

Interessting, the line and column number varies dependanding on the actual script size.

I'm using Firebird 2.5

Here is the executing script:

```
set term ^ ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
insert into TABLE (COLUMNA) values (13);
...
insert into TABLE (COLUMNA) values (14);
END^
set term ; ^
```

Comment: How are you sending this _script_ to the database engine?

Comment: why embed them to the block, instead of passing each after another. Logical data granularity should be mantained by transactions and savepoints

Comment: Oh ... I think I had some errors in my thoughts. I just changed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebird 2.5 and earlier have [a limitation of 64 kilobytes](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq197/) for the query text, for Firebird 3.0 this limit was increased to 10 MB when the new API is used. An `EXECUTE BLOCK` is one query, so it should not exceed 64 kilobyte.

Comment: but he perhaps can overcome it by internal gbak-insert batch command

Comment: And the 64kB BLR and 48kB plan, which is mentioned in your link as well.